# How to check if a thread is still alive in tomcat if I know the thread name?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have an application running on `tomcat` and I have a `static` pool (`HashMap`) where I am storing an object each time a thread is created in `tomcat` through a request and I am deleting the entry from the `HashMap` when the thread dies. Just to make it clear here is a simple example of what I am doing.

**This is my pool**

```
public class CustomerPool{

    public static Map<String, Customer> customerPool = new HashMap<String, Customer>();

    public static void createSession() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        Customer c = new Customer();
        customerPool.put(threadName, customer);
    }

    public static void terminateSession(){
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        customerPool.remove(threadName);
    }
}
```

**And my servlet**

```
public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        CustomerPool.createSession();

        //the rest of my code

        CustomerPool.terminateSession();
        return;
    }
}
```

Due to some exceptions that I am receiving (which are specific to my application and there not point to list them) I believe that sometimes entries are not getting removed from the pool.

I want to produce a report of the pool which will show how many entries are currently into the pool and for which of them the thread does not exist. Is it possible in **Java** to check if a thread is alive by knowing only the thread name?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you just keep the names in the pool instead of the thread objects themself? That would make it much easier!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `ThreadLocal` for this. If the thread dies, the ThreadLocal will be cleaned up automatically since it's a class variable for the Thread.

You can enumerate all the threads in the JVM, but it has a code 'smell' to me if you have to do that for proper function of your program.